# Запись в файл. fwrite() fread();

Tags: c, float

Доброго времени, уважаемые.

Пример взял с [сайта для изучения C++](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/09/0905.htm). При записи в файл в нем самом отображается ерунда, но не то, что надо. 
С чего бы это?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp;
  double d = 12.23;
  int i = 101;
  long l = 123023L;

  if((fp=fopen("test", "wb+"))==NULL) {
    printf("Ошибка при открытии файла.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  fwrite(&d, sizeof(double), 1, fp);
  fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
  fwrite(&l, sizeof(long), 1, fp);

  rewind(fp);

  fread(&d, sizeof(double), 1, fp);
  fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
  fread(&l, sizeof(long), 1, fp);

  printf("%f %d %ld", d, i, l);

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

fread/fwrite функции читают/пишут данные в бинарном формате. Если хочется человеко-читаемый (текстовый) формат, то можно использовать fscanf/fprintf вместо fread/fwrite соответственно.

Приведённый в вопросе код должен работать как есть.

Что конкретно fwrite запишет на диск, может зависеть от платформы (размер типа ([LLP64, LP64 модели](http://www.viva64.com/ru/t/0012/)), [порядок байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), и даже побитовое представление типов ([дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%29), обратный код), выравнивание типов).

Например, если файл скопировать на другую платформу, то не обязательно что fread сможет его прочитать корректно.

На моей машине `test` файл содержит:

```
$ xxd test
0000000: f628 5c8f c275 2840 6500 0000 8fe0 0100  .(\..u(@e.......
0000010: 0000 0000                                ....
```

Первая колонка, нумерует байты, в каждой строке по 16 байт, представленных командой `xxd` ввиде шестнадцатеричных чисел (каждые две цифры соответствуют одному байту). Самая правая колонка показывает печатаемые байты (точка используется для непечатаемых в ascii символов).

Вот байты соответствующие каждому значению:

```
  d  f628 5c8f c275 2840
  i  6500 0000
  l  8fe0 0100 0000 0000
```

Можно сразу сказать, что `int` является 32-битным типом (4 байта, предполагая 1 байт = 8 бит), а `long` 64-битным типом (что верно для lp64 модели) с порядком байтов от младшего с старшему (little-endian) на моей машине.

Если записать байты для `i` и `l` в порядке от старшего к младшему (big-endian) как обычно числа записаны на бумаге пишут:

- `int i` `00000065` в шестнадцатеричной системе соответствует `101` в десятичной системе(65<sub>16</sub> = 101<sub>10</sub>), что является корректным значением для `i`
- `long l` `000000000001e08f` в шестнадцатеричной системе соответствует `123023` в десятичной системе (1e08f<sub>16</sub> = 123023<sub>10</sub>), что также верно.

Число `d` записано как [число двойной точности в IEEE 754 формате](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) --
d = ±знак · (1 + мантисса / 2<sup>52</sup>) · 2<sup>порядок − 1023</sup>:

```
d  402875c28f5c28f6
```

(cнова переписал байты от старшего к младшему) Или в двоичной системе -- все 64 бита числа `d`:

```
d 0100000000101000011101011100001010001111010111000010100011110110
```

Самый левый бит это знак, в данном случае он `0`, то есть `d` является положительным, затем 11 бит *порядок* = 10000000010<sub>2</sub> = 1026<sub>10</sub>, оставшиеся 52 бита *мантисса*:

100001110101110000101000111101011100001010001111011<sub>2</sub>
= 2381278302972150<sub>10</sub>
= 875c28f5c28f6<sub>16</sub>

Всё вместе:

d = (1 + 2381278302972150 / 2<sup>52</sup>) · 2<sup>1026 − 1023</sup>
   = 3442438965171323 / 281474976710656
   = 12.23

`12.23` также верным значением является.

Comment: Вот это ответ!

Comment: Согласен, отлично развернуто и доступно. Спасибо за труд. Был бы благодарен, если бы сказали, что прочитать, чтобы разобраться в этом получше.

Comment: @dil: можно начать со ссылок в ответе, которые в свою очередь тоже содержат дальнейшие ссылки. Если что-то не ясно, спрашивайте.

Comment: @dil, если в двух словах, то `fwrite` записывает в файл *содержимое памяти без каких-либо преобразований* (т.е. именно те цепочки бит, которыми оперирует аппаратура компьютера (которую, Вы в свою очередь, программируете с помощью языка C/C++)), 

а `frpintf` записывает в файл эти данные уже *нужным образом преобразованные* (отформатированные для восприятия человеком в соответствии с %d, %f и т.п.).

Если хотите разобраться поглубже, то почитайте как устроен компьютер (процессор, память, адресация (виртуальные и физические адреса), машинные команды и т.д.)

Comment: @dil: в тему: [код на Питоне, который генерирует 16-битное двоичное представление для числа с плавающей точкой, используя IEEE 754-2008 (binary16) формат](https://gist.github.com/zed/59a413ae2ed4141d2037#file-binary16-py-L20-L66) (в коде также есть ссылки для дальнейшего чтения).

Answer (score 1):

в файле должно быть (при 64 битах, little-endian) :
**f628 5c8f c275 2840 6500 0000 8fe0 0100
0000 0000**

или, если смотреть в символьном виде, что то типа - 
**ö(.Âu([@e](/users/17823/e1148611)^@^@^@.à^A^@^@^@^@^@**
(сильно зависит от того, чем вы смотрите)

А что вы хотели увидеть?

Ну и на вский случай, никогда так не делайте, не пишите sizeof(T) в бинарный файл, размер и порядок следования байт pod типа зависит от разрядности и архитектуры, под которую вы собираете.

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить из-за чего в файл вместо текста/цифр выводит подобное и что это подобное собой представляет?Если не использовать sizeof(T) тогда что вместо него? И не стоит вообще использовать fwrite()и обойтись fprintf/fputs...?