# Проблема интерпретации полученных данных с сервера на C#

Tags: c#, python, клиент-сервер, типы-данных

Добрый день! Проблема следующая - мы отправляем данные на сервер, написанный на C#, при помощи Python 2.7. Пакуем и распаковываем данные при помощи стандартной библиотеки struct (pack() и unpack() соответственно).
Проблема в том, что при получении данных с сервера мы получаем странный кортеж (889192448, 67108864, 0), тогда как в теории должны получить кортеж (12, 4, 0)
Может ли это быть проблема с взаимодействием Python и C#?

```
import socket
from struct import *

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('213.177.120.34', 8024))
print('connected')

bind_struct = pack('iiii3s8s', int(calcsize('iiii3s8s')), 1, 0, 1, '111', 'password')

print unpack('iiii3s8s', bind_struct)

sock.send(bind_struct)

print 'sent'

data = sock.recv(calcsize('iii'))

print 'received'

data = unpack('iii', data)

print data

sock.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> проблема с взаимодействием Python и C#

По сети только байты летают (TCP socket—это просто поток байтов). Убедитесь, что вы все байты послали/получили:

- [`socket.send(bytes)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) не обязан все байты из `bytes` послать. Можно использовать `socket.sendall()` вместо этого, который либо все данные посылает, либо завершается с ошибкой—ключевое отличие от `socket.send()`, то что нет возможности узнать сколько байт было успешно послано до ошибки.
- [`socker.recv(bufsize)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) возвращает *самое большее* `bufsize` байт—может меньше вернуть.

Возможно вам лучше библиотекой более высокого уровня воспользоваться, к примеру [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) и посылать серверу http-запросы с данными в JSON формате:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps((12, 4, 0))
'[12, 4, 0]'
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json={"data": (12, 4, 0)}) 
>>> r.json() # response
{'args': {},
 'data': '{"data": [12, 4, 0]}',
 'files': {},
 'form': {},
 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*',
             'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
             'Content-Length': '20',
 ...
```

---

Для `4`-ки у вас неверный порядок байт: сервер посылает big-endian (от старшего к младшему) как это принято в сети, а на клиенте вы используете родной для машины порядок байт, который у вас little-endian (от младшего к старшему порядок байтов внутри числа). Пример (Питон 3):

```py
>>> int.from_bytes(4 .to_bytes(4, 'big'), 'little')
67108864
```

Следует зафиксировать порядок байт, используемых в вашем протоколе обмена между клиентом и сервером:

```py
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>i', 4)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x04'
>>> struct.pack('<i', 4)
b'\x04\x00\x00\x00'
```

Следует зафиксировать размер числа: снова по умолчанию используется родной для платформы размер (что C компилятор бы использовал), например 32 vs. 64-bit.

Убедитесь, что вы не пытаетесь послать число со знаком, как число без знака:

```py
>>> int.from_bytes((-1).to_bytes(4, 'little', signed=True), 'big', signed=False)
4294967295
```

Также при посылке составных объектов могут добавляться padding между элементами структуры, если вы используете родной формат платформы (по умолчанию или с явным индикатором формата `'@'`). Если использовать явно: `'!'`, `'<'`, `'>'` форматы, то нет padding.

Если вы бы использовали `'!iii'` формат, то *гарантировано* вне зависимости от машины, на который вы этот код запустили, что порядок байтов big-endian, размер каждого числа 4 байта, каждое число со знаком и нет padding—[см. описание форматов в `struct` документации](https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-strings):

```py
>>> struct.pack('!iii', 12, 4, 0)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> _.hex()
'0000000c0000000400000000'
```

Убедитесь, что С# именно эти байты посылает. Связанный вопрос: [Запись в файл. fwrite() fread();](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/385823/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы используете другой тип int в Python'е, попробуйте поиграться на стороне сервера или клиента с типами Int.