# printf как средство печати переменных в С

Tags: c++, c, float, io, printf

Я не знаю как точно сформулировать то, что я хочу спросить, но выглядит это следующим образом:

1. Как напечатать содержимое переменной в *С*:

   ```
   char msg = 'k';
   printf("%c", msg);
   ```
2. Как напечать содержимое переменной в *С++*:

   ```
   char msg = 'k';
   cout << msg;
   ```

А теперь вопросы:

1. В *C++* для вывода не нужно указывать модификатор, тогда почему в *С* нет аналога `cout` (я все понимаю, что язык гораздо старше *C++*, но все же)?
2. Мне часто пишут, что тип в `printf` нужно приводить:

   ```
   char msg = 'k';
   printf("%f", (float)msg);
   ```

А зачем? В аналоге *С++*, этого же не надо делать!
Почему я не могу написать так: `printf("%f", msg);`? В чем причина? Разве `printf` не приведет данные самостоятельно к тому модификатору, который мы указываем?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Why do we have to tell printf() the type of data in C?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/264089/1985)

Comment: Это разные языки с разной философией  и парадигмами. Ваш вопрос можно было бы с тем же успехом адресовать к любым парам языков.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

В C, `printf(format, msg)` в исходном коде вызывает *одну и ту* же функцию вне зависимости от типа, значения `msg` переменной. C — *статически* типизированный язык, это значит, что *во время исполнения* printf функция не знает, что `msg` это `char`, более того printf даже не знает сколько её аргументов передали. Поэтому приходится руками в `format` строке задавать желаемое представление: значение *какого типа* из памяти, в которой `msg` лежит, **загрузить** и как это значение **отформатировать**, чтобы получившиеся байты затем в stdout **записать**.

В C++, `cout << msg` для *разных* типов `msg` может скомпилировать вызов *разных* функций (перегрузки оператора `<<`). Вы легко можете определить свой оператор `<<`, к примеру, чтобы выводить векторы для отладки:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v) {
  for (auto&& x : v)
    os << x << ' ';
  return os;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3};
  std::cout << v << '\n';
}
```

Пример:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11     main.cc   -o main
$ ./main
1 2 3
```

Упрощая, можно представить, что компилятор для `cout << msg` генерирует вызов `print_char(msg)`, если `msg` это `char`, `print_float(msg)`, если `msg` это `float`, `print_vector(msg)`, если `msg` это `vector` итд. Здесь каждая функция знает какой тип она принимает и для каждого типа используется одно представление в виде байт по умолчанию, если [iomanip не используются](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)). К примеру, для `int` выводятся его десятичные цифры (а не hex или что-то другое) по умолчанию.

В [C11 появился `_Generic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic), который позволяет  разные функции в зависимости от типа аргумента (`controlling-expression`) вызывать, поэтому можно определить `print_arg(arg)`, которое бы работало для разных типов `arg` (один аргумент).

> Почему я не могу написать так: `printf("%f", msg);`? В чем причина? Разве printf не приведет данные самостоятельно к тому модификатору, который мы указываем?
>   [...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628946/printf-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%a1/628951#comment882747_628947) `printf("%f", (float)msg);` \\ `107.000000`, а `printf("%f", msg);` \\ `0.000000` почему ответ разный?

При вызове [вариативных (variadic) функций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) таких как printf, объявленных с многоточием (`...`) в параметрах, которые могут принимать разное количество аргументов c неизвестными компилятору ожидаемыми типами (С компилятор  не обязан понимать язык printf format-строки и значение `format` может быть вообще неизвестно во время компиляции), происходят преобразования по умолчанию: `char` неявно в `int` превращается (integer promotion) или в `unsigned int`, если значение `char` не представимо в `int` на данной платформе (экзотика). Аналогично, float в double превращается при вызове `printf()` — поэтому не требуется `%lf` для `double` в `printf()`, а используется просто `%f`.

Для случая, c printf можно использовать простую модель: компилятор кладёт аргументы (int, double, etc) в область памяти, а printf читает их оттуда в соответствии с инструкциями в `format` строке — printf выступает в роли мини-компьютера: format задаёт программу и printf **читает** память ([`va_arg`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg)), в которой её аргументы лежат, **форматирует** их и **записывает** получившиеся байты в `stdout`.

`(double)msg` объект может отличаться в памяти от `(int)msg` объекта. Поэтому printf может видеть разные битовые паттерны в памяти и соответственно, результат `printf("%f", (int)msg)` и `printf("%f", (double)msg)` могут быть разными (одна и та же инструкция: `%f` применяется к разному содержимому в памяти).

Пример для моей машины (как типы выглядят в памяти может зависеть от платформы (операционной системы + процессор) и опций компилятора). Байты в памяти я буду в виде hexdump показывать (к примеру: 6B<sub>16</sub> == 107<sub>10</sub>).

Для `printf("%c", msg)`:

- `'k'` в C имеет тип `int` — `6B 00 00 00`
- `char msg` — `6B`
- в printf это передаётся как `int` — `6B 00 00 00`
- `%c` берёт этот аргумент `6B 00 00 00` и превращает его в `unsigned char` (`6B`) и соответствующий байт (`6B`) выводится в stdout. См. [printf документацию для `c` формата](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Для `printf("%f", (float)msg)`:

- `msg` (`6B`) преобразуется в `(float)msg` — `00 00 D6 42`
- что передаётся в printf в виде `double` — `00 00 00 00 00 C0 5A 40`
- `%f` интерпретирует память `00 00 00 00 00 C0 5A 40` как [число с плавающей точкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/385941/23044) и выводит  в фиксированном формате (`6` знаков после запятой): `107.000000` (символ для точки от локали может зависеть). Соответствующие байты в ascii кодировке, которые в stdout пишутся: `31 30 37 2e 30 30 30 30 30 30`

Для `printf("%f", msg)`:

- `msg` (char — `6B`) передаётся в printf в виде `int` — `6B 00 00 00`
- `%f` интерпретирует память `6B 00 00 00 XX XX XX XX` как число с плавающей точкой `5.3e-322` (если `XX == 00`) и выводится `0.000000`

Так как при неверном формате поведение не определено (undefined behavior — UB), то `printf("%f", msg)` может сделать всё что угодно, хоть ракеты запустить. На моей машине результат `printf("%f", msg)` зависит от предыдущего кода к примеру:

```
char c = 'k';
printf("%f\n", (float)c);
printf("%f\n", c);
```

печатает:

```
107.000000
107.000000 # XX XX XX XX == 00 C0 5A 40 (остатки от предыдущего вызова)
```

но:

```
printf("%f\n", 5.3e-322);
printf("%f\n", c);
```

печатает:

```
0.000000
0.000000  # XX XX XX XX == 00 00 00 00 (остатки от предыдущего вызова)
```

Убедитесь, что для форматов известных во время компиляции (к примеру `"%f\n"`) ваш компилятор генерирует предупреждения для неверных типов — UB следует избегать.

> `printf("%i", (int)msg); \\\ 107 и printf("%i", msg);`

в обоих случая `msg` char передаётся как `int` (`6B 00 00 00`) и при одинаковых форматах, результат должен быть одинаковым (6B<sub>16</sub> == 107<sub>10</sub>).

Можно посмотреть содержимое переменных на вашей машине с помощью С кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_memory(unsigned char *memory, size_t n)
{
  for (unsigned char *p = memory; p != memory + n; ++p)
    printf("%02X ", *p);
  puts("");
}


int main(void)
{
  char c = 'k';
  print_memory((unsigned char *)&c, sizeof c);
  int i = c;
  print_memory((unsigned char *)&i, sizeof i);
  float f = c;
  print_memory((unsigned char *)&f, sizeof f);
  double d = f;
  print_memory((unsigned char *)&d, sizeof d);
}
```

Пример:

```
$ gcc -std=c99     main.c   -o main
$ ./main
6B 
6B 00 00 00 
00 00 D6 42 
00 00 00 00 00 C0 5A 40
```

#### Как double в памяти может выглядеть

[Пример из ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/385941/23044), применённый к `107.0`: [число двойной точности в IEEE 754 формате](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) представляется как
d = ±знак · (1 + мантисса / 2<sup>52</sup>) · 2<sup>порядок − 1023</sup>

знак, мантисса и порядок упакованы в двоичном представлении как:

```
 00 00 00 00 00 C0 5A 40 // little-endian (8 byte as hex)
 40 5A C0 00 00 00 00 00 // big-endian
 0100000001011010110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 # 64-bit
 ^
 |-самый левый бит знак=
 0 (положительный)

  ^         ^
  |---------|
Затем 11 бит порядок=
0b10000000101 (==1029)
             ^                                                  ^
             |--------------------------------------------------|
Оставшиеся 52 бита манитисса=
           0b1010110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  = 3025855999639552
  = 0xac00000000000
```

Всё вместе:

d = +(1 + 3025855999639552 / 2<sup>52</sup>) * 2<sup>(1029 - 1023)</sup>
  = 64 + 3025855999639552 / 70368744177664
  = (4503599627370496 + 3025855999639552) / 70368744177664
  = 7529455627010048 / 70368744177664
  = 107.0

Это демонстрирует, почему `107.0` может быть представлено в памяти как `00 00 00 00 00 C0 5A 40`.

#### Пример урезанной printf функции

```
#include <stdarg.h> // va_list, va_arg()

// emulate some printf() functionality using writec()
static void print(const char* format, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  int infmt = 0, is_char = 0;
  union
  {
    int i;
    double f;
  } arg;
  char buffer[23] = {0}; // enough for %c, %d, %f

  for (const char *p = format; *p; ++p) {
    if (infmt) { // print arg
      infmt = 0;
      switch(*p) {
      case '%': // "%%": print % literally
        writec(*p);
      break;
      case 'c': // "%c": print char
        is_char = 1;
        // fall through
      case 'd': // "%d": print int
      case 'i': // "%i": print int
        arg.i = va_arg(args, int); // load int arg
        if (is_char) {
          is_char = 0;
          writec((unsigned char)arg.i); // format as char, write
        } else {
          itoa(arg.i, buffer, sizeof buffer); // format as int
          for (char *pb = buffer; *pb; ++pb) writec(*pb); // write
        }
        break;
      case 'f':
        arg.f = va_arg(args, double); // load double arg
        ftoa(arg.f, buffer, sizeof buffer); // format as floating point
        for (char *pb = buffer; *pb; ++pb) writec(*pb); // write
        break;
      default:
        arg.i = va_arg(args, int); // load int arg
        scpy(buffer, "<unknown, load as int>");
        for (char *pb = buffer; *pb; ++pb) writec(*pb); // write
      };
    } else if (*p != '%') { // print literally
      writec(*p);
    } else { // *p == '%'
      infmt = 1;
    }
  }
  va_end(args);
}
```

- `switch` используется, чтобы распознать описатели преобразований (`%d`) в format-строке
- [`va_arg()`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg) загружает аргументы нужного типа
- вспомогательные функции `itoa()` и `ftoa()` форматируют int и double соответственно
- `writec()` пишет один байт в `stdout`.

Это определение `print()` достаточно для кода:

```
int main(void)
{
  char msg = 'k';
  print("%c %i %i %f %x\n", msg, msg, (int)msg, (float)msg, msg);
  print("%c ", msg);
  print("%i ", msg);
  print("%i ", (int)msg);
  print("%f\n", (float)msg);
  print("%f\n", msg); // XXX UB
}
```

Пример:

```bsh
$ cc -std=c99 print-example.c -o print-example
$ ./print-example
k 107 107 107.000000 <unknown, load as int>
k 107 107 107.000000
107.000000
```

Чтобы скомпилировать, достаточно вспомогательные функции определить (определения перед `print()` нужно вставить):

```
#include <unistd.h> // POSIX write()

static void writec(unsigned char c)
{
  write(1, &c, 1);
}

static void scpy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
  while (*dest++ = *src++);
}

static void ftoa(double d, char* buffer, int n)
{
  if (d == 107) //XXX
    scpy(buffer, "107.000000");
  else
    scpy(buffer, "XXX");
}

/// format positive int as decimal ascii digits
static char* utoa_rec(unsigned i, char* buffer, int *pn)
{
  if (i >= 10)
    buffer = utoa_rec(i / 10, buffer, pn);
  if ((*pn)-- > 0)
    *buffer++ = '0' + (i % 10);
  return buffer;
}

static void itoa(int i, char* buffer, int n)
{
  if (i < 0) {
    i = -i; //XXX ignore INT_MIN
    if (n-- > 0)
      *buffer++ = '-'; // sign
  }
  buffer = utoa_rec(i, buffer, &n);
  if (n > 0)
    *buffer++ = '\0';
}
```

Определения функций приведены, чтобы можно было пример запустить, но фактически они просто заглушками являются (не для повторного использования), чтобы только продемонстрировать одну из простейших `print(format, ...)` реализаций.

Вот [пример полной реализации `vfprintf()` из glibc](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/glibc/master/view/head:/stdio-common/vfprintf.c).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54162/discussion-on-answer-by-jfs-printf------).

Answer (score 18):

> почему в С нет аналога cout

Функциональность `cout` в языке С++ критически завязана на механизм *перегрузки функций* на уровне библиотеки, т.е. фактически на существовании доступного библиотеке (и пользователю) механизма *перегрузки функций*, а также сопутствующего механизма *перегрузки операторов*. Правильная версия функции вывода выбирается механизмом перегрузки на основе анализа типа указанного вами аргумента.

В языке С нет механизмов *перегрузки функций* и *перегрузки операторов* на уровне пользователя или библиотеки. Поэтому нет и таких внешне "типонезависимых" операций ввода-вывода.

В версии С11 стандарта языка С появился механизм [generic-выражений](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic), который может использоваться для эмуляции пользовательской/библиотечной перегрузки  функций. Этот механизм, например, используется (*может* использоваться) в стандартном заголовочном файле [`<tgmath.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/tgmath) для реализации "перегруженных" математических функций-макросов.

Но реализаций "типонезависимых" функций ввода-вывода в стандартной библиотеке не делалось. Если есть желание - можете воспользоваться этим новым механизмом и попробовать реализовать их самостоятельно.

> Мне часто пишут что тип в printf нужно приводить. А зачем? Разве printf не приведет данные самостоятельно к тому модификатору, который мы указываем?

`printf` - это так называемая *variadic* функция. Все аргументы этой функции, кроме первого, являются *variadic аргументами*. Они соответствуют `...` в объявлении списка параметров функции

```
int printf( const char* format, ... );
```

Такие аргументы передаются через особый механизм предачи параметров. Его особенностью является то, что сама функция `printf` абсолютно ничего не знает о типах фактически передаваемых аргументов и по этой причине ничего самостоятельно привести к правильному типу не может.

С чисто практической точки зрения вы можете считать, что все variadic аргументы записываются в непрерывный бинарный поток. Внутри себя функция `printf` будет читать бинарные данные из этого потока при помощи механизма `va_list/va_start/va_arg`. Что именно записано в этот поток функция `printf` сама по себе знать не может. Поэтому разбирать этот бинарный поток на части она будет в соответствии с тем форматом, который вы сами ей снаружи передали. И если вы ей "наврете" в этом формате, то она сама ничего не подозревая, будет разбирать этот бинарный поток неправильно. По этой причине все данные, которые вы кладете в этот бинарный поток, должны в точности соответствовать тем спецификаторам формата, которые вы указали в форматной строке.

Реализации не обязаны реализовать передачу variadic аргументов именно таким образом, но особенности передачи variadic аргументов эта модель иллюстрирует достаточно точно.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что в сишном стандарте нет слова *variadic*. Но зато есть упоминание *ellipsis notation*. Про соответствие типов имеет смысл добавить о *default argument promotions*.

Answer (score 6):

1. Для работы `cout` необходима перегрузка оператора `<<`, причём для каждого типа она своя, потому и не требуется модификаторов. В Си операторы не перегружаются.
2. Мне кажется, слово "приведёт" не совсем точно, я бы сказал "интерпретирует": `printf` выведет значение переменной так, как если бы она была того типа, что указан в строке формата. Переменная при этом не меняет значения. Сама `printf` не имеет возможности определить соответствие аргументов строке формата на этапе выполнения (а компилятор Си не учит программиста, как жить и где разложить себе грабли). Поэтому возможны всякие сюрпризы, если случайно допустить ошибку в строке формата и спутать типы или количество аргументов.

Comment: Да кстати `printf("%f", (float)msg); \\\ 107.000000`, а `printf("%f", msg); \\\ 0.000000` почему ответ разный?

Comment: или `printf("%i", (int)msg); \\\ 107` и `printf("%i", msg); \\\ 107` ответ одинаков

Comment: Если `msg` типа `char`, то при попытке вывести её как число, её код приводится к `int`. `float` и `double` могут занимать (зависит от системы) больше байт в памяти, поэтому читая float-значение из char-переменной `printf` "прихватывает" из стека лишние байты, выдавая неверный результат.

Comment: только почему ответ `0.000000` если он прихватывает лишние данные из стека?

Comment: Значит полученные из стека байты, интерпретированные как указано в строке формата, дают что-то около нуля.

Comment: Не надо пытаться уловить закономерность в результатах такого поведения программы. В лучшем случае не произойдёт ничего и — если повезёт — результат окажется ожидаемым. Содержимое стека в общем непредсказуемо. Если Ваш код будет выполняться в составе сложной программы, то результат каждый раз может быть разным.

Comment: подождите! он считывает данные с моей переменной или нет? если считывает тогда даже в случае если он прочитает больше чем надо должен быть результат, а его тут попросту нет! `0.000000`

Comment: Я не уверен, как именно, представлен `float` в памяти. Предполагаю два варианта: либо мантисса оказалась нулевой (прихвачены нули из стека), либо порядок интерпретирован как очень большое отрицательное число а результат в целом — как очень близкое к нулю значение. Попробуйте вывести его как `%e`.

Comment: Я не через мантису вывел, а через количество цифр после целого   `printf("%.100000f", msg)` да там действительно в этом месиве есть число означающее 'k'. И что это значит?

Comment: Что уже сказано: не следует читать более того, что записал сам или записано для тебя. Иначе — результат непредсказуем. (По уму такое поведение программиста и его программы должно быть запрещено, но компилятор Си, как я говорил, не учит нас жить.) Так можно делать только из любопытства в маленьких тестовых программах на своём компьютере но ни в коем случае не в программах, которые Вы когда-нибудь напишете для кого-то ещё.

Comment: Любые закономерности, какие Вы сумеете найти неверно читая стек, могут оказаться неверными в другой операционной системе или на компьютере другой архитектуры.

Comment: То есть если тип меньше int, а я пишу спецификатор %i то все ок т.к переменная приведется к int'у. Но если тип более int'а то мне нужно тогда приводить тип?! Так что ли?

Comment: Надо просто указать в строке формата тот тип, переменную которого Вы хотите вывести. Если переменная типа `char`, то выводить её надо с помощью `%c` (`%i`, если интересует ASCII-код символа).

Comment: Просто я слышал что printf некоторые типы может неявно привести, поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: Неявно приводятся меж собой (к более ёмкому типу) интегральные типы `%i` (char как целое, short, int, long) и вещественные `%f` (float, double, long double). Так что ждать, что `printf()` каким-то образом распознает, что ей подсунули `char` вместо  `float` и выведет его именно как `char`, не приходится. Такие "неочевидные" преобразования программист выполняет сам (когда они в самом деле ему нужны).

Comment: @ИльдарХайруллин `%d` и `%i` взаимозаменяемы в `printf`. Использовать `%i` для `long` нельзя. `long` не участвует в *integer promotions*. Также нельзя использовать `%f` с `long double`, в этом случае надо использовать `%Lf`.

Comment: @MaximPro, вы эксперименторовали с какой 32/64-bit? системой и каким компилятором?

Comment: @avp этим - https://repl.it/languages/c там кстати написано gcc version 4.6.3

Comment: @MaximPro, `printf("Hello World %zd %zd\n", sizeof(void *), sizeof(long));` выводит `8 8`, `system("uname -a")` печатает `x86_64 GNU/Linux`, подтверждая это. Следовательно (как вы уже знаете) первые несколько аргументов вообще в регистрах передаются. И даже вывод  `97.000000
97.000000` такой программы `char c = 'a';
  printf("%f\n", (float)c);
  c = 'b'; 
  printf("%f\n", c);`  вам должен быть понятен