# Как узнать минимальное положительное целое число не представимое в float?(и других машинных арифметиках)

Tags: c#, c++, python, c

Хотелось бы узнать как правильно найти минимальное целое число не представимое в float и десятичной арифметике с заданной мантиссой и экспонентами(минимальная,максимальная)

Comment: [Для Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3477332/5741205)

Comment: Это смотря в каком формате. Вы имеете в виду IEEE 754?

Comment: @VladD да. IEEE 754

Comment: "...и десятичной арифметике" - что за "десятичная арифметика" имеется в виду? И что такое "заданная мантисса и экспонента"?

Comment: @AnT десятичная машинная арифметика

Comment: @rdorn: Вопрос о целых числах, к которым константа Epsilon не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: @Yopp вы вероятно имеете в виду "floating point arithmetic". Также числа обычно представлены в двоичной системе `sys.float_info.radix == 2` ([пример как число `107.0` в виде бит выглядит](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629010/23044))

Comment: **Минимальное положительное целое число** - это ЕДИНИЦА!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В С константы

```
FLT_MANT_DIG
DBL_MANT_DIG
LDBL_MANT_DIG
```

из `<float.h>` дадут вам количество цифр в мантиссе соответствующего плавающего типа. Каждая цифра мантиссы - в базе `FLT_RADIX` (обычно 2). В С++ те же значения можно также получить через `std::numeric_limits<type>::digits`.

Соответственно, все целые числа, чей модуль не превосходит FLT_RADIX<sup>FLT_MANT_DIG</sup> должны быть представимы. А вот

FLT_RADIX<sup>FLT_MANT_DIG</sup> + 1

будет первым (минимальным) положительным целым не представимым в типе `float`.

Почему так? Так устроены плавающие типы. Если убрать не относящиеся к делу детали, то плавающее двоичное значение представляется по принципу

значение = мантисса * 2<sup>экспонента</sup>

Если полагать, что мантисса - целое число<sup>(1</sup>, то при любом значении экспоненты больше 0, в последовательности представимых таким способом целых чисел будут "дырки". Например, очевидно, что при экспоненте 1 представимы будут только четные числа. Непрерывная последовательность целых чисел возможна только при нулевой величине экспоненты, а также в точке перехода от экспоненты 0 к экспоненте 1.

Для экспоненты 0 диапазон ограничен диапазоном значений самой мантиссы. В типе `float` ширина мантиссы - 24 (это `FLT_MANT_DIG`). Соответственно диапазон представимых целых идет от 0 до 2<sup>24</sup>-1. А затем, при переходе к экспоненте 1 мы получаем еще одно представимое целое число: 2<sup>24</sup>. А вот следующим представимым целым числом при экспоненте 1 будет только 2<sup>24</sup>+2. Так что число 2<sup>24</sup>+1 - это первая "дырка" в последовательности представимых целых чисел.

Проверим

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  static_assert(FLT_RADIX == 2, "Ya krevedko");

  {
    unsigned long long i = 1ull << FLT_MANT_DIG;
    float f = i;
    printf("%llu %f\n", i, f);
    f = ++i;
    printf("%llu %f\n", i, f);
  }
  {
    unsigned long long i = 1ull << DBL_MANT_DIG;
    double f = i;
    printf("%llu %lf\n", i, f);
    f = ++i;
    printf("%llu %lf\n", i, f);
  }
}
```

Вывод

```
16777216 16777216.000000
16777217 16777216.000000
9007199254740992 9007199254740992.000000
9007199254740993 9007199254740992.000000
```

Таким образом в IEEE 754 типа `float` первое непредставимое целое число - это `16777217`, а для типа `double` - это число `9007199254740993`.

Та же формула применима и к десятичным представлениям с плавающей точкой, построенным на тех же принципах.

---

<sup>1)</sup> В реальности в IEEE 754 все несколько по-другому. Мантисса - это двоичное число с точкой вида `1.000...0` шириной в 24 бита (т.е. 23 двоичных знака после точки), и соответственно идущие подряд целые числа будут представляться при значениях экспоненты до 23. А начиная со значения экспоненты 24 будут представляться уже только четные целые числа. Но на вышеприведенные рассуждения это не оказывает принципиального влияния. Принципиальный момент тут в любом случае один и тот же - непрерывный диапазон целых чисел определяется шириной мантиссы.

Comment: В Питоне: `sys.float_info.radix**sys.float_info.mant_dig + 1`

Comment: @AnT Спасибо. Последний вопрос почему именно по такое формуле находится?

Comment: @AnT Есть формула для представления числа x = мантисса*основание степени*показатель степени.
в питоне мантисса для float = 53 основание степени = 2 и возьмем максимальный показатель степени = 1024
получим совершенно другое число

Comment: @Yopp Во-первых, ваш питоновский `float` с 53 битами в мантиссе - это, очевидно, Сишный `double`. Во-вторых я не понимаю, что вы пытаетесь продемонстрировать, беря максимальный показатель степени. Да, получим совершенно другое число. И какой из этого следует вывод? Что вы этим хотите сказать?

Comment: @AnT Я не так понял, уже разобрался. Спасибо большое