# Магическое изменение значения переменной после scanf

Tags: c

Всем привет. Столкнулся с какой-то абсолютно мистической проблемой.

Есть код на Си:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
unsigned int  a, A = 0;
unsigned short tmp = 0;
scanf("%u", &a); // вводим значение, будем считать, что 3
//a = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    printf("--%u\n", a); // a == 3
    scanf("%u", &tmp);
    printf("--%u\n", a); // внезапно а == 0
    A |= 1 << tmp;
}

return 0;
}
```

*Примечание: Если раскомментировать строку `//a = 3` и убрать первый `scanf`, все адекватно работает.*

Надеюсь, из комментариев в коде все понятно. Переменная `a` в цикле каким-то магическим образом меняет свое значение после строки `scanf("%u", &tmp);`

Ломаю голову уже часов 5, поэтому прибежал к вам. В чем вообще тут проблема может скрываться?

Comment: scanf функция во время исполнения не знает тип tmp переменной. Если не тот тип передать, то может даже от порядка вызовов printf (только для чтения функция) результат меняться. [printf как средство печати переменных в С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628946/23044)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте написать не `scanf("%u", &tmp);`, а `scanf("%hu", &tmp);`: у вас же `short int`, а не `int`...

Comment: Черт, помогло, спасибо. Опять на пустяках ошибки.
Но почему так? Ведь в scanf в цикле значение пишется в абсолютно другую переменную.

Comment: Ну, принимайте ответ :)

Comment: Приму, но разрешит только через 8 минут :)
Я понял причину. `scanf`, видимо, забивает нулями больше чем нужно и тем самым переписывает переменную `a`.

Comment: Ну на это я как бы и намекал - он же считает, что вы передали адрес int'а, вот и перезаписывает рядом лежащую переменную...

Comment: Самое забавное, что у меня уже вторая такая наиглупейшая ошибка, только до этого с long была. Ну да ладно, может кому-то с таким же вопросом поможет ;)

Comment: В первом scanf был int.

Comment: @Qwertiy Бывает же! Я написал. Потом подумал, посмотрел, *увидел*, что `a` тоже `short`, дописал... Как это может быть - не понимаю, но помню четко... Спасибо, исправился.