# Неверный результат побитового НЕ

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Почему возникает ошибка при выводе результата унарной операции `~`?
(должно было ведь получиться  `~a = 0`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    unsigned char a = 0xff;

    printf("a = %u\n", a);
    printf("~a = %u\n", ~a);

    return 0;
}
```

Результат (компилятор - Clang) :

```
a = 255
~a = 4294967040
```

Comment: Где-то идёт неявное преобразование char в int (правда, где именно, я не в курсе)

Comment: Дело всё в том, что тип `unsigned char`  подвергается целочисленному продвижению (integral promotion) и преобразуется либо в `int`, либо в `unsigned int` (это в том случае, если `int` не может представить все значения `unsigned char`). Таким образом, при, например, 8-битном `unsigned char` и 32-битном `int` кажется, что происходит инверсия последовательности битов: `11111111`, а на **самом деле** происходит инверсия такой последовательности битов: `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`.

Comment: После инверсии вы получаете последовательность битов `11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000` и именно эта последовательность битов и передаётся в функцию `printf`. А за счёт спецификатора типа `%u` функция `printf` интерпретирует данную последовательность битов как `unsigned int`, т.е. как числовое значение `4294967040`.

Comment: Также рекомендую ознакомится с ответами к [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628946/printf-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%A1) вопросу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Результат `~a` имеет тип `int`*, и вычисляется обращением битов *после* превращения `a` в `int` (integer promotions, так как int может представить все значения unsigned char, если не рассматривать редкий случай когда `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`). В [с11 (n1570)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The result of the ~ operator is the bitwise complement of its (promoted) operand (that is,
>   each bit in the result is set if and only if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is
>   not set). The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the
>   promoted type. If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the expression ~E is equivalent
>   to the maximum value representable in that type minus E

К примеру, на одной из возможных реализаций:

```
(~a) -> ~(FF) -> ~(00 00 00 FF) -> FF FF FF 00 = -256
```

Затем `%u` интерпретирует `int` как `unsigned int`, поэтому для примера выше: `printf()` получает `-256` (FF FF FF 00) и выводит `4294967040` (34 32 39...).

`0` вы получите, если `(~a)` назад в `unsigned char` превратить:

```
unsigned char b = ~a;
```

в этом случае `-256` в ноль превращается (§6.3.1.3/2) так как вычисления по модулю `UCHAR_MAX+1` происходят (`UCHAR_MAX=255` здесь). `printf("%u", b)` выведет `0`.

Аналогично, в случае с `%hhu`: `printf()` получает `int` (FF FF FF 00) и интерпретирует его как `unsigned char` для печати:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char a = 0xff, b = ~a;
    printf("a=%d b=%d ~a=%d\n", a, b, ~a);
    printf("a=%u b=%u ~a=%u\n", a, b, ~a);
    printf("a=%hhu b=%hhu ~a=%hhu\n", a, b, ~a);
}
```

[Результат](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%23include%20%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint%20main%28void%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20unsigned%20char%20a%20%3D%200xff,%20b%20%3D%20~a%3B%0A%20%20%20%20printf%28%22a%3D%25d%20b%3D%25d%20~a%3D%25d%5Cn%22,%20a,%20b,%20~a%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20printf%28%22a%3D%25u%20b%3D%25u%20~a%3D%25u%5Cn%22,%20a,%20b,%20~a%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20printf%28%22a%3D%25hhu%20b%3D%25hhu%20~a%3D%25hhu%5Cn%22,%20a,%20b,%20~a%29%3B%0A%7D&cumulative=false&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=c&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

```
a=255 b=0 ~a=-256
a=255 b=0 ~a=4294967040
a=255 b=0 ~a=0
```

Comment: @mega как я вам уже сказал. %hhu это часть Си стандарта, любой Си компилятор обязан её поддерживать и нет нужды указывать какой компилятор используется (к примеру я не знаю какой компилятор использует pythontutor откуда  я результаты скопировал). Если ваш компилятор не поддерживает стандартную функциональность, то можно задать отдельный вопрос: "как эмулировать %hhu"

Comment: "к примеру я не знаю какой компилятор использует pythontutor откуда я результаты скопировал" -- вообще-то он Вам пишет и компилятор и версию (как раз для таких случаев - gcc4.8). A я просто Вам покажу то же, что и @Harry: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOYBF.png (vs2013)

Comment: Так исторически сложилось, и [ms этого не скрывает](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx) (правда - и не аргументирует): "The hh, j, z, and t length prefixes are not supported"

Comment: У Вас тут много комментариев, и я в них тоже особого смысла не вижу. Я просто обратил внимание остальных на то, что код в обоих ответах не даст ожидаемый вывод в VS. И по ссылке можно почитать документацию, которая это подтверждает, если кого-то конечно интересует "что там ms делает с %hhu".

Comment: Можно еще добавить в примерах, что `printf("%u", (unsigned char)~a);` тоже выведет ожидаемый 0

Comment: @mega, `%u` предполагает, что в качестве аргумента был передан, как это ни странно `unsigned int`. В примере @avp последовательность преобразований такая: `a` расширяется до `int`, затем делается инверсия битов, затем `int` явно приводится к `unsigned char`, затем `unsigned char` посредством integer promotions расширяется до int для передачи в `printf`, затем `printf` интерпретирует этот `int` как `unsigned int` и выводит. Собственно всё :)

Comment: @wololo, дело не в том, что это работает, когда есть поддержка неявных преобразований, а в том, что нехорошо передавать в функцию `char`, когда ожидается `int`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69992/discussion-on-answer-by-jfs----).

Comment: @mega, нет, передавать char  вместо int вполне нормально, поскольку при передачи аргументов в функции char всегда расширяется до int, поэтому разницы никакой.

Comment: Нет, @Qwertiy, передавать `char`, когда ожидается `int` - уже ненормально, это вызывает лишние вопросы, которых в ответе быть не должно.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("~a = %u\n", ~a);
```

`%u` говорит о том, что вы хотите вывести `unsigned int`. Так что вы получаете приведение к этому типу с последующей инверсией битов. Хотите получить 0? Тогда делайте так:

```
unsigned int a = 0xffffffff;

printf("a = %u\n", a);
printf("~a = %u\n", ~a);
```

Или, если нужен один байт - используйте верный префикс - `%hhu`:

```
unsigned char a = 0xff;

printf("a = %hhu\n", a);
printf("~a = %hhu\n", ~a);
```

Comment: "используйте верный префикс - %hhu" -- он не везде поддерживается, в виндах, например, его нет

Comment: @mega: %hhu это стандартный Си.

Comment: %hhu не поддерживается в vs

Comment: [`~a` уже имеет тип int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/756050/23044) и поэтому `~a != 0`, а `%u` только превращает int в unsigned int здесь.

Comment: @mega Ну, у меня в VC++ поддерживается...

Comment: printf("%hhu", -1); Если выводится `255`, значит поддерживается, а если `65535` - нет. VS поддерживает только `%hu`.

Comment: @mega http://i100.fastpic.ru/big/2017/1209/18/233305f6b084f75c4cda9708b1c99618.jpg - устроит? или вам надо TeamViewer'ом к себе на машину пустить и показать? :)

Comment: Да нет, верю. Вот Вам аналогичный скрин: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgYlh.png (vs2013), аналогично будет в 2010, 2008, 2005