# Почему printf("%f", 'a'); будет 97?

Tags: c

```
float x = 'a';
printf("%f", x);
```

ответ дается в цифрах: 97,00000
Не могу понять как такой ответ получаеться кто может объснить ?

Comment: Вопросу следует давать нормальное название, отражающее его суть

Comment: связанный вопрос: [printf как средство печати переменных в С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628946/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В языке С лексический элемент `'a'` называется *целочисленной символьной константой* (integer character constant). Целочисленная символьная константа в С имеет тип `int`. На вашей платформе значение этой константы оказалось равно `97`.

Именно это значение вы и наблюдаете в выводе.

Answer (score 0):

[ASCII-код](http://www.asciitable.com) символа "a" - 97 (0x61)

Comment: можно сказать что у каждого символа есть свой код и это не имеет значения что оно в float или int или char?

Comment: Да, у каждого символа свой код, char обычно эквивалентно знаковому байту от -128 до 127 (точнее определено в `limits.h`). Тип значение имеет, но C позволяет довольно вольно обращаться с данными разных типов. Впрочем, присвоение значение целого типа вещественной переменной во многих языках не требует явного преобразования.

Comment: спасибо отличное объяснение