# Форматирование вывода float в python3

Tags: python

Есть 2 числа. При их умножении, float изменяет их формат

```py
>>> x = 0.0001347
>>> y = 0.0005388
>>> print(x*y)
>>>7.257636e-08
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вывести число в привычном виде `(0.0000000726)` c типом float и с фиксированным количеством знаков после точки типа `(".10f" %(x*y))`

Comment: `print("%.10f" %(x*y))`

Comment: в чём отличие `"%.10f" % f` от желаемого? Ясно ли вам, что float внутри компьютера не хранится ни в 1e-2 ни в 0.01. Формат имеет значение  только когда вы строковое представление хотите. [Пример как число с плавающей точкой в памяти представлено](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/385941/23044)

Comment: отличие в том, что у меня есть значение 0.0000000726, python преобразует его в 7.257636e-08, я добавляю его в список, при извлечении из списка, я не могу "переконвертировать" его в float и получаю ошибку, ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'e'
Я вообще не хочу, чтобы число конвертировалось в формат с 'e', возможно ли, как-то этого добиться?

Comment: @leexxg: `"%.10f"` формат никогда вам `'7.257636e-08'` строку из float не выдаст. Вы возможно не тот код, который думаете выполняете. Создайте минимальный но полный пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему. Явно приведите ввод, желаемый вывод и что вместо этого получается [mcve]. Используйте \@ синтакс, если хотите, чтобы уведомление о вашем комментарии пришло. Информацию необходимую для ответа следует в сам вопрос помещать. Нажмите [edit]

Answer (score 1):

В привычном виде, это значит, в строковое представление числа, при этом само число не меняется.

```
>>> x = 0.0001347
>>> y = 0.0005388
>>> z = (x*y)
>>> print("%.10f" %(z))
0.0000000726
>>> z
7.257636e-08
```

Answer (score 1):

Мода на `f-string`, поэтому можно вот так с этим работать

```py
>>> x = 0.0001347
>>> y = 0.0005388
>>> print(f"{x*y:.10f}") 
0.0000000726
```

[Здесь можно почитать на англ](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)