# Вместо значения 0.06 выводит 0.060000000000000005, так же с 0.09, 0.1 и т.д

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется код:

```
f1 = 0
    f2 = 4
    n = 0
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 0.01
    print("#    x1      x2      f1      f2")
    while n <= 9:
        n = n + 1
        x1 += 0.01
        x2 += 0.01

        print(str(n) + "    " + str(x1) + "     " + str(x2) + "     " + str(f1) + "     " + str(f2))
        print(end="")
```

Вот, что выводит:

```
#       x1              x2              f1              f2
1       0.01            0.02            0               4
2       0.02            0.03            0               4
3       0.03            0.04            0               4
4       0.04            0.05            0               4
5       0.05            0.060000000000000005            0               4
6       0.060000000000000005            0.07            0               4
7       0.07            0.08            0               4
8       0.08            0.09            0               4
9       0.09            0.09999999999999999             0               4
10      0.09999999999999999             0.10999999999999999             0          4
```

Должно выводить так:

```
# x1  x2  f1    f2
0 0.0 0.1 1.22  1.24
1 0.1 0.2 1.24  1.255
2 0.2 0.3 1.255 1.39
…
9 0.9 1.0 2.93  3.1415
```

И подскажите пожалуйста как правильней сделать табуляцию.

Comment: так питон же вроде умный, сам пробелы ставит при выводе

Comment: по теме:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756164/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-float-%D0%B2-python3

Comment: Считайте максимальную длину числа в данном столбике и от него играйте. Кол-во пробелов после числа = макс длина числа в данном столбике - длина числа + 1. "Макс длины после числа в данном столбике" можно занести в одномерный массив